# hive function returning wrong date

Tags: sql, hive

```
hive> select from_unixtime(UNIX_TIMESTAMP('02/31/17', "mm/dd/yy"),'yyyy-MM-dd') from dual;
OK
2017-01-31
```

It is returning wrond date.

Comment: you know that the date you are trying to parse is an invalid one..right?

Comment: why is it invalid?

Answer (score 0):

Found it.Date format is wrong.

```
select   from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('12/31/17' ,'MM/dd/yy'), 'yyyy-MM-dd') from dual;
```